# Android sqlite data insertion issue

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i have created a database with the table name tbl_customer and tbl_product...i can view the tbl_customer values but can't see tbl_product values.. I use adb shell to confirm my insertion. Can any one plz help me to figure out the issue

```
private void addProFromDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

        try {
            list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            sampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, 1, null);
            sampleDB.execSQL("create table tbl_product("
                    + "pro_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
                    + "pro_name text," + "pro_price integer);");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES
                    + " Values ('1','Milk','60');");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES
                    + " Values ('2','Sugar','70');");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES
                    + " Values ('3','Oil','200');");
            Cursor c = sampleDB.query(SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES, null, null, null, null, null,
                    null);
            char pro_nameColumnIndex = (char) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pro_name");
            int pro_priceColumnIndex = (int) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pro_price");

        } finally {
            if (sampleDB != null)
                sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES);
            sampleDB.close();
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, new ArrayList()));

        new AddStringTask().execute();
    }
```

Also help me how i can get its primary key and display the selected value...
Best regards....

Comment: read documentation of execSQL again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is a good idea to consider using the `insert()` method on `SQLiteDatabase`, instead of executing `INSERT` statements via `execSQL()`, particularly if you do not have much SQL experience.

Second, normally, an `INSERT` statement lists the columns to be inserted into, which you are not doing. SQLite might support your syntax, but it makes for more fragile code.

Third, with an `autoincrement` column, you do not assign your own values, as you are trying to do.

Fourth, you are putting string values into `integer` columns. SQLite supports that, but not by actually converting the values to integers, but rather storing the strings themselves in the columns, which may not be what you want.

Fifth, `getColumnIndexOrThrow()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Sixth, you are deleting your data from the table milliseconds after inserting it, in your `finally` block, assuming that `SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES` is set to `tbl_product`. If those values are not equal, then you are inserting into and querying from a table that does not exist.

Seventh, your `Cursor` is dead as soon as you `close()` the database in your `finally` block.

Some combination of those probably explains "the issue".

Comment: special thanks for your time and prompt response, i am doing the same thing with other table,i.e., tbl_customer, it is not only creating the table but also writing the string values+autoincrement.. the only diff is that i am populating tbl_customer into spinner, while tbl_product is multi checklist..it creates the table (confirmed from adb shell) but not showing the inserted values..